# Download ListView all items data as a Single text file in android

Tags: android, file, listview, download

I have a ListView that has been Listed with a some values using JSON. so my requirement is I just need to download the ListView items as single text file into sdcard when I click a download button, for each download each text file should be created with a continue name like
File1, File2, File3....

So I implemented FILE concept and created a Function in a button click

```
String str1=null;
str1=title.getText().toString();
generateNoteOnSD("sample.txt", str1);
```

"title" is the name of a TextView in the ListView item

### generateNoteOnSD function

```
public void generateNoteOnSD(String sFileName, String sBody){
        try
        {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
```

### My ListView look like this [image: listview]

how to implement this download concept... any ideas.. Thanks.

Comment: how to collect all the item textview datas? i have four values in each items..

Comment: it's easy. get the selected row data by using it's `position` like: `names.get(position)` and so on.... .Here names is an String of `array` or `ArrayList`